# How to change instance tenancy from Dedicated to Shared?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running an instance in Dedicated tenancy. To avoid the higher charges (and per-region fee), I want to change the machine to shared tenancy for debugging. How can I achieve this without creating an AMI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you will need to create an AMI and launch it with the tenancy that you want - there is no other way.